# How to overwrite type information when serializing objects with jackson?

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson

I'm currently trying to serialize data that I've previously loaded via Hibernate. To recover type information I enabled default typing like this:

`objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS,As.PROPERTY);`

I also added identity-info to my entities via this anotation:

`@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")`

However when I deserialize `@OneToMany`-relations that I have, deserialization fails because the PersistentBag does not have a session at this point. Because my programm is running without a container I can not fix this issue easily.

I'm also aware of the fact that there is this hibernate-datatype module for jackson but this doesn't solve the problem (I guess that module is primaliry used for respecting the LAZY_LOADING-hibernate-property).

So my idea to fix this was to not serialize a `PersistentBag` but an `ArrayList` instead. Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to write my own serializer (which I tried but without beeing successful)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this with a workaroung by adding the Type-information via annotation to the classes I wanted to serialize and by removing the default-typing-line:

> objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS,As.PROPERTY);